# Which software can I use for backups?

Tags: windows, backup, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a simple home backup software which works with a variety of OSes?](https://superuser.com/questions/7511/what-is-a-simple-home-backup-software-which-works-with-a-variety-of-oses)

I need software that will take incremental backups of a few folders on my drive and back them up to an external HDD.  I want to have a feature where I can 'mount' the backup and get files out of it should I need to. Acronis does this but unfotunately doesn't work properly on my setup... :-( Any ideas what I can use?

Comment: It would be nice to know why acronis does not work on your setup, maybe that problem could be fixed or at least no one would reccommend a solution that leads to similar problems.

Comment: Syncback from 2brightsparks is a fairly nice program that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Genie Timeline Home](http://www.genie9.com/home/home_solutions.aspx). Its [free edition](http://www.genie9.com/free_products/free_timeline.aspx) is also available.

It does incremental backup very smoothly & features `Time Machine of Mac OS X`. Means, you can move back & forth in time to access your file system snapshots at that time. Its the true power of incremental backup (beyond storage saving etc).

Answer (score 0):

Many external drives ship with software that does this type of backup. Western Digital and Maxtor on many.  I am sure others as well.  What make external drive do you have?  Check the vendor site.